# Using both Inheritance and Composition in the same class?

Tags: java, oop, class, inheritance, composition

I know the rule of using inheritance when there is an is-a relationship, and composition when there's a has-a relationship, but are the two mutually exclusive/replacements for one another or would there be a case where you should use both in the same class?

I've Googled a lot but only found articles explaining when you use each, rather than both.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are *not* mutually exclusive. Example: `Boat` and `Sailboat`. `Sailboat` is-a `Boat`, but it has-a `Sail`, which other `Boat`s may or may not have.

Answer (score 4):

[`Decorator`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern is a classic example where the decorating class is composed of an instance to the decorated object of the same class and extends/implements the same class.